# Creating a SHA-256 hash in OrientDB Function

Tags: orientdb, sha

I need to store a password's SHA-256 hash in OrientDB REST function - so I can use it to authenticate the user. The incoming call to the REST function will contain the password (over HTTPS) but I want to generate a hash and store that instead of the password itself.

However, OrientDB does not expose any helpers to do this. And straight javascript does not have helpers to do this either... any way I can make this happen?

(one obvious option is to SHA-256 it in the middle tier and pass that to OrientDB but I'd rather keep this in the database tier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OSecurityManager from Javascript functions like this

```
return com.orientechnologies.orient.core.security.OSecurityManager.instance().digest2String("password");
```

Comment: Awesome info @wolf4ood